# Can I delete my own question?

Tags: discussion

I have a challenge, that I don't like.  I think the challenge has a negative impact on the community, and I think we would all benefit from it being gone.  I decided I was willing to part with my meager rep gains, so I went to delete it. However I was told I could not because it had an answer.  So instead I cut it down to a stub and voted to close as off topic.  This was reverted as vandalism, which in retrospect it probably was.

As the challenge asker is there any way to get a bad challenge of mine deleted or closed?  What rights do I have to a challenge that I wrote?  Can I disown my challenge?

Comment: Don't know enough for a proper answer, but in my opinion you should explain to the answer's poster and hope that they agree with you and delete their answer, so you can delete the question.

Comment: @FryAmTheEggman Thats a good idea.  Unfortunately I have *14* answers meaning I would have to convince 14 users, which may be a hard task.  Especially because some of them have made over 200 rep off of their answers.

Comment: In that case, I think the strongest action you can take is to open a meta discussion like: "Should question X be closed/locked/deleted?" Where you can explain why you think the question is bad for the site. If people agree, mods could lock/delete the question. I don't think there's a clean way to "disown" a challenge without deleting your account. Individual mistakes aren't very important, the best way to gain trust is to write good challenges going forward, imo. I don't know enough to be sure, though, so this is mostly just my opinion.

Comment: Did you post this just to make people look through all your old challenges to find it? If so, well played...

Comment: You can not delete it...
But there is one thing we can do: before post our answer, or our question, we have to think if it is good to post it...

Answer (score 7):

**As the challenge asker is there any way to get a bad challenge of mine deleted or closed?**

No. You can take part in a closure, but you still need more people that agree with you.

**What rights do I have to a challenge that I wrote?**

It is still *your* challenge, but by posting it

> [y]ou grant Stack Exchange the perpetual and irrevocable right and license to use, copy, cache, publish, display, distribute, modify, create derivative works and store [it].

<sup>[source](https://stackexchange.com/legal/terms-of-service#3SubscriberContent)</sup>

That means Stack Exchange can prevent you from deleting it, editing it down to a stub, etc.

**Should I disown my challenge by making a community wiki?**

If you simply don't want it to be *your* challenge anymore, [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/96746/170332) is you best option imo.

> If you would like to have your name disassociated from that post, you can request we do so by clicking on the 'contact us' link at the bottom of the page.

Answer (score -3):

## no

You can not delete it.

But there is one thing we can do:
first of post our answer or post our question, we have to think if it is good to post it....