# Unable to Delete and Unable to Close Vote

Tags: discussion

I've got [a question](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/208982) that I really don't like (does not meet my standards, has repetitive answers because I did not realize how many languages had built-in functions for transpositions, etc).

<s>I would edit to fix those things but that would bump the question to the top of the page, and besides, I would still dislike it then.</s> I cannot delete the question because it has too many answers, and I cannot cast a close vote because I have ~1500 rep. Should I just sit and wait for its closure at this point? (it is garnering close votes at this very moment)

Comment: The easiest way to avoid this is to simply avoid asking questions.

Comment: [Related answer](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/13270/31625). Possibly essentially the same question, but I think the underlying reason for wanting to remove the question were somewhat different.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First: I'm sorry you feel this way. This site is supposed to be a source of enjoyment, not pain.

That said, I don't think you need to feel bad about it. There are plenty of challenges that have trivial answers in powerful languages, but as of this writing, you have:

- 12 upvotes (vs only 3 downvotes)
- Over 600 views (in less than 24 hours)
- 20 answers (over a handful non-trivial ones)

This is nothing to be ashamed of. Experienced challenge writers have done worse.

Going forward, I think the wisest thing to do is to utilise [the sandbox](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges), but even then, you shouldn't worry too much; this site *is* all about having fun while becoming better.

Comment: I'll add that in my experience, pretty much any linear-algebra challenge is bound to attract languages with copious linear-algebra built-ins, and I don't think there's really anything you can do about that.